# Can't convert a list of objects with a child list if the child list is empty using linq?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have this bit of code to convert one list of objects to another list of objects. The code works fine but not if the Messages property is empty. I thought using Any with the ?: operator would fix it but it hasn't, instead I get a Null Reference Exception.

```
var TemporaryMessageGroupList = MyList.Select(x => new MessageGroupModel()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            DisplayPicture = x.DisplayPicture,
            LastMessage = x.LastMessage,
            Archived = x.Archived,
            Messages = (x.Messages.Any() ? x.Messages.Select(y => new MessageModel()
            {
                Id = y.Id,
                CreatorId = y.CreatorId,
                Content = y.Content,
                TimeSent = y.TimeSent,
                GroupId = y.GroupId,
                HasAttachment = y.HasAttachment,
                AttachmentImage = y.AttachmentImage,
                IsRead = y.IsRead
            }).ToList() : new List<MessageModel>()),
            Members = x.Members.Select(c => new UserModel()
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                FullName = c.FullName,
                DisplayPicture = c.DisplayPicture
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

I just want to be able to convert one list of objects to another like above, if anyone knows another way to do it to overcome the issue, let me know, thanks!

Comment: `x.Messages != null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Any` upon `Messages` will yield the said exception if `Messages` is null, instead do:

```
 Messages = x.Messages?.Select(y => new MessageModel()
            {
                Id = y.Id,
                CreatorId = y.CreatorId,
                Content = y.Content,
                TimeSent = y.TimeSent,
                GroupId = y.GroupId,
                HasAttachment = y.HasAttachment,
                AttachmentImage = y.AttachmentImage,
                IsRead = y.IsRead
            }).ToList() ?? new List<MessageModel>(),
```

- This uses the "null-propagation" operator `?.` to prevent calling `Select` on `Messages` if it's null.
- We then use the "null coalescing" operator `??` to generate a new empty list in the case of `Messages` being null.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this, Make sure that x.Messages is not NULL and prefered to be an empty collection if empty, also make sure the properties for Messages are not null for the original object or they are nullable on the receiving object:

```
Messages = (x.Messages?.Where(msg => msg != null).Select(y => new 
MessageModel() {}).ToList()
```